# How to completely remove AdobeCleanUpUtility & AdobeGCClient from MacOS?

Tags: macos, icons

Is there a way to completely remove AdobeCleanUpUtility & AdobeGCClient from Launchpad and from MacOS?

[image]

I have tried the following method and was able to delete both icons but when I reboot the laptop, they will reappear like a virus.

```
1. Drag the icon onto dock
2. Right click icon on the dock, click "options" then click "show in finder"
3. Drag icon into trash
4. Empty your trash.
```

**UPDATE:**

Finally figured it out! Here are are the steps to removing AdobeCleanUpUtility & AdobeGCClient from Launchpad and from MacOS?

1. Go to “Application” folder
2. In the “Search” bar, on the upper right corner, type in “AdobeGCClient”

[image]

3. Right beneath the search bar click on the “+” icon on the upper-right corner

[image]

4. On the “Name” drop down menu located in the left-upper corner, select “Others…”

[image]

5. Then scroll all the way down and select “System files” ( make sure the check mark is on )

[image]

6. Back on the “Name” drop down menu select “System files”

[image]

7. After which, delete all the files you see related to “AdobeGCClient”
8. Repeat the same process from step 1 to 7 for “AdobeCleanUtility”

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to completely remove AdobeCleanUpUtility and AdobeGCClient from Launchpad and MacOS. The steps you have mentioned are correct, but it seems like the files are being automatically restored upon reboot.

To permanently remove the files, you can try the following steps:

1. Open Terminal on your Mac.
2. Type in the following command:    `launchctl remove com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and wait for the command to execute.
4. Type in the following command: `sudo rm -rf "/Library/Application Support/Adobe/AdobeGCClient"`
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and enter your password when prompted.
6. Type in the following command:  sudo `rm -rf "/Library/Application Support/Adobe/AdobeGCClient"`
7. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and enter your password when prompted.

These commands will remove the Adobe Creative Cloud launch agent and the AdobeGCClient and AdobeCleanUpUtility files from your system. This should prevent the files from being automatically restored upon reboot.

Please note that modifying system files can be risky and may cause unintended consequences, so proceed with caution and make sure you have a backup of your system before making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

See the official guide about removing Adobe utilities: [https://helpx.adobe.com/in/genuine/uninstall-adobe-genuine-service.html#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20Control%20Panel,Genuine%20Service%20and%20select%20Uninstall](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/genuine/uninstall-adobe-genuine-service.html#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20Control%20Panel,Genuine%20Service%20and%20select%20Uninstall).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).